# Can I use WOPI instead of WEBDAV with MS Word desktop application

Tags: ms-word, webdav, ms-wopi

Right now we are using a WEBDAV host to serve and handle documents for our application which users can process with their MS Word desktop application.

My goal is to replace this WEBDAV host with a WOPI host. For now this still should keep working with MS Word desktop application.

I am unable to find examples/articles which discuss this possibility and how this can be done. All examples/articles I found are about integration of Office for web into your application. That is just not what we want now, that is something for the longterm.

I hope someone can tell me or point me in the right direction if it is possible to use a WOPI host with MS Word desktop application to replace WEBDAV?
And if so, what steps to follow?

Until now I spend most of my time searching for examples and articles on how I could achieve my goal of replacing our WEBDAV host with a WOPI host to serve/handle documents with MS Word desktop application.

And I have been playing around with a WOPI host example project (https://github.com/petrsvihlik/WopiHost) to see if I could let MS Word desktop application work by using the url from the WOPI host to open a document.
The document does open but that's it. MS Word does not use the other WOPI calls when handling the document.

I hoped MS Word desktop application noticed it was a WOPI hosted url when opening the document.

Comment: AFAICS WOPI is only there to support the Web/Online versions of Word etc., not the desktop versions - if you read through the articles around https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/cloud-storage-partner-program/online/scenarios/createnew that becomes quite clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to allow editing in MS Word by implementing just WOPI. To enable this functionality, you need to set the WOPI CheckFileInfo's `ClientUrl` to a URL that either supports [WebDAV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/cloud-storage-partner-program/rest/files/checkfileinfo/checkfileinfo-other#clienturl) or, according to some sources, [MS-FSSHTTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sharepoint_protocols/ms-fsshttp/05fa7efd-48ed-48d5-8d85-77995e17cc81).

Comment: So that means WOPI cannot be used as a replacement for WebDAV? But you can let WOPI use WebDAV.

Comment: Correct. You can configure a WOPI client to use WebDAV as an extension. Btw - hoi Richard :) long time no see. I didn't realize it was you posting the question. feel free to ping me directly (e.g. via LinkedIn)